# flavorDimensions gradle error - Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to upgrade my project to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 and the gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 plugin, however I have a problem with the correct definition of flavors for included projects.

I followed the official migration guide from Google: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

In my main app build.gradle I defined the "myflavor" *flavorDimensions*, as recommended by the migration guide:

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "myflavor"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "myflavor"
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            dimension "myflavor"
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            debuggable false

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':util')
}
```

In my included :util module (producer), I tried to include it withouth a definition of flavorDimensions, productFlavors and buildTypes. I get the following gradle error:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:prodDebugCompileClasspath'.
  Cannot choose between the following configurations on project :util:
    - debugApiElements
    - releaseApiElements
  All of them match the consumer attributes:
    - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
        - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
        - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
        - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
        - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
    - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
        - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
        - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
        - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
        - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
```

When defining the same flavorDimensions, productFlavors and buildTypes in :util as in the main :app, I get the following error message:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:prodDebugCompileClasspath'.
Cannot choose between the following configurations on project :util:
  - devDebugApiElements
  - devReleaseApiElements
  - prodDebugApiElements
  - prodReleaseApiElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration 'devDebugApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=devDebug}' but wasn't required.
      - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
      - Found myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=dev}' but wasn't required.
      - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
  - Configuration 'devReleaseApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=devRelease}' but wasn't required.
      - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
      - Found myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=dev}' but wasn't required.
      - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
  - Configuration 'prodDebugApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=prodDebug}' but wasn't required.
      - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
      - Found myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but wasn't required.
      - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
  - Configuration 'prodReleaseApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}' but no value provided.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency. 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=prodRelease}' but wasn't required.
      - Required myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but no value provided.
      - Found myflavor 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=prod}' but wasn't required.
      - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' and found compatible value 'for compile'.
```

What is the correct way to include my :util lib without getting the error?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the Gradle build process, I'm not quite sure why exactly it's not working. I was stuck on this for a while but I was able to fix it by changing

```
compile project(':util')
```

to

```
compile project(path: ':util', configuration: 'default')
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Moez for your help. Works like a charm :-) Best regards

Comment: This bug is not fixed yet as of gradle-4.1-rc-1-all and gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta2. Took more than an hour figuring this out.. Thanks!!

Comment: while this works, it somehow prevents the transitive dependencies of `utils` to be exported so my build fails a bit further

Comment: I filed a comment there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65867056

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue using Canary 2, but the proposed solution didn't work. Apparently there is a way to use the implementation from a Local library or project:

```
// This is the old method and no longer works for local
// library modules:
// debugCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'debug')
// releaseCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'release')

// Instead, simply use the following to take advantage of
// variant-aware dependency resolution. You can learn more about
// the 'implementation' configuration in the section about
// new dependency configurations.
implementation project(':foo')
```

[Reference from Studio Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html).

Comment: what about flavors here?

Answer (score -1):

From https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65867056:

You should have only one buildScript block in the root build.gradle.
If you are using Composite builds, this is not currently supported by our plugin due to limitations in Gradle.

EDIT: I guess this now works for latest versions of gradle

Answer (score -1):

I got around this by using gradle 4.3 (with Android Studio 3.0)

**To use it with Android Studio 3.0:**

1. Download the binary here: https://gradle.org/releases/
2. Configure local gradle binary in Android Studio, under preferences...

[image]

3. Then in your gradle file replace **compile** with either **implementation** or **api** depending on your requirements.

references:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

**ALSO:** make sure that your external modules (i.e util) have the same flavors as your App or you will get the error outlined in here: [Gradle 4.0 Unable to find a matching configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218614/gradle-4-0-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration)