# Gradle could not resolve project :linkedin-sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, linkedin-api

I'm using Androis Studio 3.0 Canary 4. In my project i have the Linkedin-sdk, and it works. I can use it. The only problem is that i recive this message when i search to build Gradle.
[image]

And because i'cant build it i cannot use the designe editor and the preview.

Here is my build.gradle project:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com'
       }
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.Gradle Module:App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.cving_team.cving"
           minSdkVersion 19
           targetSdkVersion 26
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner 
           "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
signingConfigs {...}
buildTypes {
    sdkTest {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.sdkTest
        debuggable true

    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
        core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

compile project(':retrofit-2.1.0')
compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.mutualmobile.android:cardstack:0.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
compile 'eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc1'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Linkedin-sdk is in settings.gradle to.

```
include ':app', ':retrofit-2.1.0', ':fabby-sdk-jni', ':linkedin-sdk'
```

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I have launched this command from terminal: gradlew tasks, and recive this error:

```
> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :fabby-sdk-jni
Configuration 'compile' in project ':fabby-sdk-jni' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':fabby-sdk-jni' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':fabby-sdk-jni' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.

> Configure project :linkedin-sdk
Configuration 'compile' in project ':linkedin-sdk' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':linkedin-sdk' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testSdkTestUnitTest'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:sdkTestUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :linkedin-sdk.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :linkedin-sdk:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=sdkTest}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found incompatible value 'for compile'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=sdkTest}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found compatible value 'for runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=sdkTest}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found incompatible value 'for compile'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=sdkTest}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found compatible value 'for runtime'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

**SOLVED**

Just chenage:

`compile project(':linkedin-sdk')`

to

`compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')`

Comment: Can you show your `settings.gradle`?

Comment: Like i said before is already included. Have updated.

Comment: you don't have a second `settings.gradle` in `app/`, do you?

Comment: And does the same error happen if you build from the commandline?

Comment: No i haven't. I haven't try to  build from commandline. Try and tell you

Comment: Sorry, how can i do it?

Comment: `gradlew`        ___________

Comment: Ok, also i runned gradlew in the terminal, had the problem "could not find gradle 3.0.0-alpha4". So i have fixed him (Updated my gradle.build code above). Then i have relaunched gradlew and had no issues. But still when i try to sync i recive the same "could not resolve project" error.

Comment: Waith, have tried new thing. Have updated my question

Comment: This looks like android specific problem, so I'm out of the loop, but maybe now with the additional infos someone can find the right answer

Comment: Where do you have the linkedin-sdk project?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have solved the problem. Look at question on the bottom

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: I don't know that. Thanks

Comment: Also, it will help if you edit your question to show what version of Android Studio you are using.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038946/383414

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved my problem. In build.gradle(Module app) `buildTypes` must have this structure:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    releaseSdk {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.sdkTest
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

and in build.gradle(Module linkedinn-sdk) buildTypes must have same structure. So the new code is:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp  {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    releaseSdk {}
}
```

Comment: Almost a year later and this is still the best answer. buildTypes across modules need to have the same types.

Answer (score 28):

Since you are using the new android plugin 3.x you have to follow the [migration guidelines](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html):

> Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :linkedin-sdk.

To resolve this error, you need to specify which build type from "mylibrary" (linkedin-sdk in your case) the Android plugin should match to the app's "staging" build type. You can do this with the `buildTypeMatching` property in the app's `build.gradle` file, as shown below:

```
android {
    ...
    // Tells the Android plugin to use a library's 'debug' build type
    // when a 'staging' build type is not available. You can include
    // additional build types, and the plugin matches 'staging' to the
    // first build type it finds from the one's you specify. That is,
    // if 'mylibrary' doesn't include a 'debug' build type either, the
    // plugin matches 'staging' with the producer's 'release' build type.
    buildTypeMatching 'staging', 'debug', 'release'
}
```

**Edit**:
`buildTypeMatching` [was replaced](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/09/android-studio-30-beta-4-is-now.html) by `matchingFallbacks`.
You can find more info about the variant-aware dependency management
 [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#variant_aware) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors).

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        release {}
        staging {
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback build types that the
            // plugin should try to use when a dependency does not include a
            // "staging" build type. You may specify as many fallbacks as you
            // like, and the plugin selects the first build type that's
            // available in the dependency.
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'qa', 'release']
        }
    }
}
```

Then

> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :linkedin-sdk:

You can use

```
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')
```

but you can  simply use the following to take advantage of variant-aware dependency resolution. .

```
implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
```

You can learn more about the `'implementation'` configuration in the section about new dependency `configurations`.

Comment: i use this in android 3.2 for multiple module geofence,chat and work...thanks

Comment: This seems to be removed in newer gradle versions - one should now define "fallback" build types as per [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038946/383414)

Comment: Do you import the linkedln sdk via jar library or the lib. project ?

Comment: `Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildTypeMatching()'`

Comment: @m0skit0 buildTypeMatching was replaced by matchingFallbacks with plugin 3.0 beta4. You can find more info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#variant_aware and here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors

Answer (score 13):

I got similar error that I was able to resolve:

```
21:13   Gradle sync failed: Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :sTLivenessLibrary:
        - debugApiElements
        - debugRuntimeElements
        - releaseApiElements
        - releaseRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
        - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
        - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
        - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for compile' but wasn't required.
        - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
        - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
        - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
```

I fixed this by changing the compile config:

```
compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
```

to

```
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default').
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is

`implementation project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')` works

And you can choose **flavour type** in left tab `Build Variants`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue when updated to android studio 3.0

This was my build types block in app gralde file

```
 buildTypes {
    staging {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://compute.amazonaws.com/"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'REGION_CODE', '"1"'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    QA {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"com.amazo/"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'REGION_CODE', '"92"'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    notificationTest {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://a6a"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'REGION_CODE', '"92"'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

and this was my project dependencies

```
compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
compile project(':scatter')
```

I opened scatter build.gradle and slideDateTimePicker build.gradle files and replaced android block with this one.

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    QA {}
    notificationTest{}
    releaseApp {}
    releaseSdk {}
    staging{}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to import the LinkedIn SDK as a module in your Android Studio project. To do this

1. Extract the project from the ZIP file which you downloaded from LinkedIn.
2. In the Android Studio menu, navigate to Android File -> New -> Import module and then select the folder which you created in step 1.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38998826/1440565

Comment: Like i said on the question i have solved the problem. And the linkedin sdk as always worked. It was not a problem of import. It was just a bug of Gradle. Here is some more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114044/flavordimensions-gradle-error-android-studio-3-0-canary-1