# How to add android library dependency to a kotlin module?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, modularity

I have a simple project that contains two modules within android my app. One is a kotlin module and another an android library. I would like to add the android library as a dependency to the kotlin module. However when I try I get an error `Could not resolve project :androidlibrary`.

Is there any way to implement an android library into a kotlin module?

### kotlin module Build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":androidlibrary"))
}
```

### android library Build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
...
}

dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it solved a related module inclusion problem for me:

Make sure that you have a JavaVersion that is "same enough" in the two modules!

I tried importing a project with `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.Version_17` (i.e. v17) into a module with `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion_1_7` (i.e. v1.7) which made the latter silently ignore the classes from the former  without even giving me an error on gradle sync.

Making sure that everything has the same JavaVersion everywhere (or at least > 1.7) solved my own dependency including problem; hopefully it works for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [Gradle could not resolve project :linkedin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830256/gradle-could-not-resolve-project-linkedin-sdk)

Just change:

```
implementation(project(":androidlibrary"))
```

to

```
compile project(path: ':androidlibrary', configuration: 'default')
```

Comment: `compile` is deprecated and replaced with `implementation`, which doesn't work either