# android studio 3.0 : Could not resolve project :fun:push. Required by: project :business:diary

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Unable to resolve dependency for `':business:diary@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :fun:push.`

Could not resolve project :fun:push.
Required by:
    project :business:diary

> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :fun:push:
>        - Configuration 'jpushDebugApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'jpushDebug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required map 'amap' but no value provided.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>            - Required push 'jpush' and found compatible value 'jpush'.
>        - Configuration 'jpushDebugMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value

I have already read [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors), but i add missingDimensionStrategy location not app module `build.gradle` file. Created a new file `config.gradle` as:

```
project.ext {
setDefaultConfig = {
    extension ->
        extension.android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 22
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                multiDexEnabled true
                missingDimensionStrategy 'map', mapImplFlavor//add to here
                missingDimensionStrategy 'push', pushImplFlavor

                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi', 'x86','armeabi-v7a'
                }
                javaCompileOptions {
                    annotationProcessorOptions {
                        arguments = [moduleName: project.getName()]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        println("extension : " + extension.android.defaultConfig.getMissingDimensionStrategies().toString())
}
```

Also, for all module `build.gradle` imported this file:

``````
apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/config.gradle"
apply plugin: AutoBuild
android {
    project.ext.setDefaultConfig project  //import above code
    resourcePrefix "diary_" 
`````
``````

Finally when I use set AutoBuild plugin to automatically apply `com.android.application` or  `com.android.library` plugin (That is, not directly in the `build.gradle` file)and other operation. This problem appears when I Sync or Clean project, but build is a success.

I found that AutoBuild plugin is running first,Then it's `config.gradle`, I also added `inject missingDimensionStrategy` in AutoBuild plugin, but it doesn't resolve. Please help!

Comment: Can you please post the `settings.gradle` file of your main project?

Comment: settings.gradle:`include ':app',
    ':buildsrc',
    ':business:diary',
    ':business:memberCenter',
    ':business:mall',
    ':fun:push',
    ':fun:map',
    ':baseLib:core',
    ':baseLib:fecCommon'`

Comment: what's your gradle version? look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114044/flavordimensions-gradle-error-android-studio-3-0-canary-1), it may help you.

Comment: Okay out of those module names which are mentioned in your `settings.gradle` have you deleted any one? For eg. if you have deleted `:fun:map` from the project structure but forgot to delete `:fun:map` from the `settings.gradle` file. Can you please check that?

Comment: no,I didn't delete any one. 
   I think `com.android.builder.core.DefaultProductFlavor#missingDimensionStrategy(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`perform need a explicit apply com.android.application or com.android.library in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Finally I added the following code in module `build.gradle`file resolve this problem:

```
apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/config.gradle"

if (!gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString().toUpperCase().contains('ASSEMBLE'))    {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
} else {
    apply plugin: com.fec.buildgradle.AutoBuild 
}

android {
    project.ext.setDefaultConfig project
    resourcePrefix "diary_" 
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

 // in runtime following code is invalid just for sync and clean
    if (!gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString().toUpperCase().contains('ASSEMBLE')) {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile "src/main/runAlone/AndroidManifest.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project.ext.dependencies["constraint-layout"]
    annotationProcessor project.ext.dependencies["arouterCompiler"]
    api project(':baseLib:core')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It gave me the same error and I tried all the suggestions mentioned here, but it didn't work. Then I just created another fresh project and it worked fine. I know this is not the solution but just a work around.